# Error while trying to host Laravel project on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run a Laravel project on shared hosting.

I am getting the following error: `Target class [App\HTTP\Controllers\PostsController] does not exist.`

My `routes/web.php` is as following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', [
'uses' => '\App\HTTP\Controllers\PostsController@index',
'as' => 'home'
]);
```

Here's what I have done:

1. Copied `index.php`, `style.css` and `.htaccess` from public folder to root.
2. Changed `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` in index.php
3. Changed `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

I uploaded the entire project one and as a whole in htdocs of the server. Still I am getting the error. While trying to run the project this way on my localhost (wampserver) by creating a Virtual Host, everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: probably because you are not paying attention to case sensitivity .. the folder is most likely `Http` not `HTTP` so  `App\Http\Controllers\PostsController` ... you also don't want to upload this as a whole ... put the code up then use composer to get all the depenencies

Comment: Okay that worked. I guess I am just stupid :/

Comment: nah,  some filesystems just don't care about case, others do ... just keep it in mind for the future ;-)